# Is the probability that a spherically symmetric random number is in a cone always the same, no matter the specific distribution?

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, control-theory

**Definitions:**

Let $C_n$ be a [generalized cone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedCone.html) (but with the interior included, i.e., the $C_n$ is solid, not just a surface) in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with vertex at the origin. The following may not be crucial, but in the case I'm working with $C_n$ is furthermore open, non-convex and simply-connected.

Now let us pick a random number from a spherically symmetric multivariate distribution, i.e., some random variable $\Theta X$, where $\Theta$ is a random vector distributed uniformly over an $n$-sphere and $X$ is a random variable with support over $(0,s)$, where $s$ can either be some finite, positive number or positive infinity.

For a given $n$, there is some probability that $\Theta X\in C_n$, call it $p(n)$.

**Question:**

Is $p(n)$ the same, no matter the choice of $X$ (when $X$ is defined in accordance with the above)?

**Context:**

This seems to be the case when $C_n$ is the space of $n\times n$ [Hurwitz-stable matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix#Hurwitz_stable_matrices) (and $\Theta$ is drawn from an $n^2$-sphere) and I thought this could be explained by [this space being a cone](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005109897002173) (as defined above), but I'm not sure how one would show this.

Comment: $\Theta$ lives in the $(n-1)$-sphere, not the $n$-sphere, right?

Comment: Since $X$ is a positive scalar, $\Theta X\in C_n$ exactly when $\Theta\in C_n$, by definition of "generalized cone", isn't it? Thus $P(\Theta X\in C_n)=P(\Theta\in C_n)$ because it's the same event, and the latter doesn't even mention $X$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm By "$n$-sphere", I mean the surface of an $n$-ball, so the object is $n-1$-dimensional, but I'd still say it lives in $n$ dimensions. W.r.t. your last comment, could you expand on this/show it very "dumbed-down" (preferably in an answer)? I don't see why the first part of the comment is (probably trivially) true, even though it was my intuition from the start.

Comment: The [usual convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) is that an $n$-sphere is an $n$-dimensional manifold that embeds into $(n+1)$-dimensional space. So a circle is an 1-sphere, and ordinary sphere is a 2-sphere and so forth.

Comment: Also, what _is_ your definition of "generalized cone" if it does not immediately imply that multiplying a point by a positive scalar cannot change whether the point is in the cone or not?

Comment: @HenningMakholm W.r.t. your latter comment: Of course you're right, I was simply being dull, I see why you mentioned $X$ as a positive scalar now! Feel free to post your second comment as an answer, I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is a positive scalar, $X\Theta\in C_n$ exactly when $\Theta\in C_n$, by any reasonable definition of "generalized cone".

Therefore $P(X\Theta\in C_n)=P(\Theta\in C_n)$ because it's the same event -- and the latter doesn't even mention $X$.